# Load data to mySQL and ignore specific columns

Tags: mysql, data-import

I am trying to load a csv file into mySQL. I want to ignore 3 columns so I am using the '@' character to achieve that. It seems that everything is being uploaded apart from the data after the first column I ignore (named : 'ignore1').

Is this a bug of mySQL software?

```
   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Z:/test.csv'  
    INTO TABLE IN_Apolo
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS
    (name, @date, @ignore1, @ignore2, @ignore3, column3, column4)
    set date = str_to_date(@date,'%Y-%m-%d')
    ;
```

**column3** and **column4** appear to be NULL

UPD:

I tried using this code and it works:

```
   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Z:/test.csv'  
    INTO TABLE IN_Apolo
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS
    (@name, @date, @column3, @column4)
    set name=@name, date = str_to_date(@date,'%Y-%m-%d'), column3=@column3, column4=@column4     ;
```

but it should work with the first version too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Z:/test.csv' 
INTO TABLE IN_Apolo 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@name, @date,@column3, @column4)
set name=@name,date=str_to_date(@date,'%Y-%m-%d'),column3=@column3,column4=@column4;
```

Try using this...

Comment: Check for the Updated one.. remove the columns which u don't want to use.. becuase your file might be having only 4 columns so it is taking values till @ignore2 others it is taking null.

Comment: That is what I just did and it worked. That is strange though. it should work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Table:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_table`;

CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
    `name` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `date` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
    `ignore_1` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ignore_2` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ignore_3` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `column_3` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `column_4` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

File:

`/path/to/test_file.csv`

```
"name","date","ignore_1","ignore_2","ignore_3","column_3","column_4"
"name_0","2000-01-01","ignore_1_0","ignore_2_0","ignore_3_0","column_3_0","column_4_0"
"name_1","2000-01-02","ignore_1_1","ignore_2_1","ignore_3_1","column_3_1","column_4_1"
"name_2","2000-01-03","ignore_1_2","ignore_2_2","ignore_3_2","column_3_2","column_4_2"
```

MySQL Command-Line:

```sql
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/test_file.csv'
       INTO TABLE `test_table`
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
       ENCLOSED BY '"'
       LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
       IGNORE 1 ROWS
       (`name`, @`date`, @`ignore_column`, @`ignore_column`, @`ignore_column`, `column_3`, `column_4`)
       SET `date` = STR_TO_DATE(@`date`, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Comment: It works now. Thank you.  I still have an unanswered one :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503879/load-an-xlsx-file-into-mysql-table-or-convert-it-to-csv-in-php